# Additional square bracket is getting added while accumulating json array in json object

Tags: arrays, json

Please clarify me why am i getting additional square bracket while storing json array in json object

json version used : json-20140107.jar

```
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    jsonArray.put("value");
    jsonObj.accumulate("A", jsonArray);
    System.out.println(" jsonObj " + jsonObj);
```

output:

```
jsonObj {"A":[["value"]]}
```

old behavior:

```
jsonObj {"A":["value"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the method [is implemented to wrap the value in another array if it is already one](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.json/json/20140107/org/json/JSONObject.java#JSONObject.accumulate%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Object%29):

```
public JSONObject accumulate(String key, Object value) throws JSONException {
    testValidity(value);
    Object object = this.opt(key);
    if (object == null) {
        this.put(key,
                value instanceof JSONArray ? new JSONArray().put(value)
                        : value);
    } else if (object instanceof JSONArray) {
        ((JSONArray) object).put(value);
    } else {
        this.put(key, new JSONArray().put(object).put(value));
    }
    return this;
}
```

Comment: i know that. but in old versions, it is handled properly

Comment: thatsy i raised here to ask reason behind this @marvin